# How dnorm() works with a vector of quantiles in an sapply loop

Tags: r

I am working through *Statistical Rethinking* by Richard McElreath and am confused by how some code he uses on p.84 works. The code uses Bayesian grid approximation to derive two model parameters, `mu` and `sigma`, to estimate the distribution of height in a sample.

Here is the code

First we make a list of candidate `mu` values

```
mu.list <- seq(from = 140, to = 160, length.out = 200)
```

Then a list of candidate `sigma` values

```
sigma.list <- seq(from = 4, to = 9, length.out = 200) # grid of candidate sigma values
```

Then we make a data frame with every possible combination of `mu` and `sigma`.

```
post <- expand.grid(mu = mu.list, sigma = sigma.list) # expand grid so every mu is matched with every sigma
```

Which is a dataset with 40000 rows.

```
nrow(post)

[1] 40000
```

Now say we have a sample of measured heights, containing 5 measurements.

```
heights <- c(151.76, 139.70, 136.52, 156.84, 145.41)
```

Now for the part I don't understand, a reasonable complex `sapply` loop that calculates a log-likelihood for each of the 40000 candidate combinations of `mu` and `sigma`, based on the sample of five height measurements.

```
postVec <- sapply(1:nrow(post), function (i) sum( dnorm( 
      heights, # vector of heights
      mean = post$mu[i], # candidate mean height value from corresponding position in grid
      sd = post$sigma[i], # candidate sigma value from corresponding position in the grid
      log = TRUE) ) # make values logs
)
```

What we get from this is loop is a vector 40000 values long, one value for each row of the `post` dataframe.

```
length(postVec)

[1] 40000
```

What I don't understand is that if we take the `dnorm()` out of the loop and use single values for the mean and sd, but pass the same 5-value sample vector of heights in the first argument, like so

```
dnorm( heights, mean = 140, sd = 4, log = TRUE )
```

We get five values

```
[1]  -6.627033  -2.308045  -2.683683 -11.167283  -3.219861
```

So my question is: **why does the sapply loop passed into the** `postVec` **vector above yield 40000 values, not 5 x 40000 = 200000 values?**

Why does the `dnorm()` function return five values outside the `sapply()` loop but (seemingly) only one value within it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `sum` before `dnorm`: in each of the 40000 cases it sums those 5 values as to compute the log-likelihood of the whole `heights` rather than just individual observations.

For instance, without `sum` for just two combinations we indeed have

```
sapply(1:2, function (i) dnorm( 
  heights,
  mean = post$mu[i],
  sd = post$sigma[i],
  log = TRUE)
)
#            [,1]       [,2]
# [1,]  -6.627033  -6.553479
# [2,]  -2.308045  -2.310245
# [3,]  -2.683683  -2.705858
# [4,] -11.167283 -11.061820
# [5,]  -3.219861  -3.186194
```

while with `sum` we have column sums of the above matrix:

```
sapply(1:2, function (i) sum(dnorm( 
  heights,
  mean = post$mu[i],
  sd = post$sigma[i],
  log = TRUE)
))
# [1] -26.00591 -25.81760
```

Comment: Ah yes, the `sum()`. I hate missing simple little things like that. Thank you once again @Julius Vainora. I shouldn't do these things at 6am on Sunday mornings. At least I understand what's going on now.